# Permanent fix for “Do you want to change the color scheme to improve performance?” warning?

Tags: windows-7, aero, dwm, perfmon

I have a problem where `dwm.exe` keeps suggesting I disable Aero to improve my performance whenever I play either Battlefield 3 or Anno 2070.

I get three choices:

- Disable Aero
- Don't disable but ask again.
- Don't disable and never ask again.

The last one is the only acceptable choice. But still it doesn't keep the pop up from appearing every time I run a full-screen application.

I've tried:

1. Changing Action Center settings to not show Windows Troubleshooting messages.
2. Disabling Windows Performance Logging and Alerts in the service manager.
3. Making changes to perfmon.

**Disabling Desktop Composition, either on a by-program basis or completely, is NOT a valid solution to this problem.**

There is no problem with my resources or performance, I just want to get rid of this Windows bug.

Again, to clarify: my rig can handle running Aero, VLC with a 1080p movie in one screen and Battlefield3 at 120fps in the other without as much as a hickup, I just want the pop-up gone for ever without having to sacrifice Aero.

I've had Windows 7 x64 on three machines by now, some much lower-performing than my current, and it is the first time I'm having this problem.

Please help!

Comment: Sounds like you should contact the game developers and request an enhancement.

Comment: I get the same behaviour, but only if I minimize the game that's running - I assume because the DWM is not rendered behind any full-screen applications.  I'd love to know if there's a way to permanently disable this warning as well.

Comment: @martineau, and what about the dozens of other programs that trigger it? It’s not a problem with the game, it’s Windows that needs to be more user-friendly.

Comment: Have you tried clicking **Don't disable and never ask again**? As it suggests the Aero will be left enabled, and this question will never be asked again.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Based on "*that doesn't keep the pop up from appearing every time I run a full-screen application*" it would seem that option doesn't work as intended. Anyway, as far as I know, the message itself is triggered when Windows detects that the system is running low on video memory. So one workaround might be to lower VRAM usage in the games - reduce texture sizes and lighting quality, disable anti-aliasing and triple-buffering, etc.

Comment: @Indrek I must have misunderstood it. What is the size of video memory?

Comment: On the question that TFM linked I personally use [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/360190/19943) which essentially boils down to finding the offending (offensive) application and disable desktop composition *for that application* which pretty much fixes it.

Comment: After some more testing, this appears to be a Glitch or Bug within Windows. I've now tried many more fullscreen-applications, and regardless of whether I use DX11 or DX9, this message pops up for no reason. Whenever I run the same applications in windowed mode, this does not occur, the performance of the system however, heavily decreases.

To sum it up:
- Pop-up appears when performance of the system is good.
- Pop-up does not appear when performance is low.
- Cannot be disabled.
- Bug that only Microsoft can fix.

Now, how do I contact Microsoft support...?

Comment: I've now upgraded my graphics card to a GTX680 from Point of View, with 2 GB of dedicated ram, running Battlefield 3 at medium settings, the pop-up still appears. This is getting ridiculous. How can Windows still think that my system has performance issues? With an i7 3770K and 8GB ram?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've finally found a solution!

Since Windows doesn't understand how resources work, you need to keep it from checking them:

In regedit go to:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\DWM** 
(create if not already existent)

Set a new DWORD **UseMachineCheck** with a value of **0**.

This will keep Windows from checking if your computer "performs slowly" and thus attempting to disable Aero.

Solved all my problems!

Comment: nope , didn't work for me. the message still appears.

Comment: Didn't work for me either. Maybe its for vista but not win7

Comment: I can confirm that this _doesn't_ work...

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the message itself, although this will most likely disable other messages relating to performance.

```
- Go to your Action Centre, type that into your Start Menu and open it.
- Choose "Change Action Centre Settings" from the sidebar on the left.
- Untick the "Windows Troubleshooting" checkbox near the bottom of the window.
- Click "OK".
```

That should subdue the message for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I've already stated in the original post, the checkbox "Windows Troubleshooting" has no apparent function, it has not disabled the pop-up or any other system related baloon or pop-up.

Answer (score -2):

The solution comes in two steps:

**step 1:**

1. Open up Quicktime
2. Edit > Prefrences > QuickTime Preferences
3. Advanced Tab
4. Under Video in Advanced click Safe Mode

**step 2:**

Run menu > sysdm.cpl > Advanced Tab > performance > select adjust for best performance > make sure you do not allow Windows to choose for you because your computer does not know whats best --- Make sure Enable Aero Peek is checked

---- OR ---

Right click my computer > properties > Advanced System settings > performance > select adjust for best performance > make sure you do not allow Windows to choose for you because your computer does not know whats best --- Make sure Enable Aero Peek is checked

note: if you are using "Doublesight DS-70U" , a bad "smart USB monitor" driver might be the cause.

note2: this [link](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/84867-how-turn-off-application-compatibility-engine.html) might also be of help.

credits: [forum link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/windows-7-automatically-switching-to-basic-non/7f4917ff-135d-40e4-866b-ac760642763f?page=3)

Comment: I don't see how this could be a solution. I have this exact problem and I don't even have Quicktime installed, not to mention setting performance settings like that will degrade the appearance of everything, which is exactly what the OP wanted to avoid. Frankly, I think you've pasted the answer to an entirely different problem into this question.