# Performance Warning with high specs

Tags: aero

As described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/314570/disable-do-you-want-to-change-the-color-scheme-to-improve-performance-warning?newreg=521ea12c81ce49d4aae275413faa8b53) I'm getting the above message with these specs:

FX8350
GTX960 4GB
16GB 1600Mhz RAM
1440p Monitor
PNY 240GB SSD
3 HDDs in JBOD mode ~3TB

Is this normal? Any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked to see what resources may be heavily allocated when the message pops up? Mostly GPU memory or RAM usage.

Comment: How to fix it depends entirely on what you were doing when it came up.  If you were running a game at uber-high texture detail then this might not be all that surprising and "fixing" it means turning the game settings down a bit.  If you were using a Excel at the time then you might have an actual problem.

Comment: This is a known issue that won't be fixed. Upgrade to a newer Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

All the operating system is showing you is that your system is running a little bit slow.

No matter how fast the machine is, the load you put on it will determine how efficiently it can run.  If you don't like that warning, follow the advice listed in the link you included.

If you want to know what uses much resources on the machine, open the `Task manager` or the `Resource monitor` to clarify it.